# Room and RX Java

Tags: rx-java2, android-room

I have a method in which a data sheet is committed.

```js
private void saveItemsToDB(List<NewsEntity> newsEntityList) {
     Disposable disposable = Completable.fromCallable((Callable<Void>) () -> {
            newsDatabase.getNewsDao().deleteAll();
            Utils.log("******Delete All******");
           
            for (NewsEntity newsEntity : newsEntityList) {
                Utils.log("******Save " + newsEntity + "******");
                newsDatabase.getNewsDao().insert(newsEntity);
            }
            return null;
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
```

I need to save them to the database. I work with Room. There is a method

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  void insertAll(NewsEntity... newsEntities);
  
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  void insert(NewsEntity newsEntity);
```

No saving occurs [Link](https://github.com/industradamus/BusinessCard/tree/temp_branch/app/src/main/java/com/example/indus/businesscard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `RxJava2` documentation, it's not allowed to pass `null` through rx chain. I suppose, it's the cause of the problem.

```
Completable.fromCallable((Callable<Void>) () -> {
    ...
    return null; // don't do this
})
```

If you don't want to return anything, use [`Completable.fromAction()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromAction-io.reactivex.functions.Action-)